# Printing multiple webpage items from json dictionary

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I am using Python.org version 2.7 64 bit on Windows Vista 64 bit. I have the following code that is pulling the data from the javascript 'Datastore.prime' item embedded within the HTML for the page referenced in the code:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags
from scrapy.cmdline import execute
import csv
import re
import json

filepath = "C:\\Python27\\Football Data\\test" + ".txt"

with open(filepath, "w") as f:
    f.write("")
    f.close()

class MySpider(Spider):

    name = "goal2"
    allowed_domains = ["whoscored.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/705/Archive/Israel-Maccabi-Haifa"]      

    def parse(self, response):

        playerdata = re.search(re.escape("DataStore.prime('stage-player-stat', defaultTeamPlayerStatsConfigParams.defaultParams , ") + '(\[.*\])' + re.escape(");"), response.body).group(1)

        for player in json.loads(playerdata):
            print player['FirstName']
```

This works great and gives a list of all the player first names contained within the main table on the page. However, when i have tried to print multiple fields from the datastore like 'FirstName' and 'LastName' by amending the print statement to 'print ['FirstName', 'LastName'] in get the error:

```
    print player['FirstName', 'LastName']
 exceptions.KeyError: ('FirstName', 'LastName')
```

Can anyone tell me why this isn't working and how I can amend the code to return multiple fields of data from Datastore.prime?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you evaluate `player['FirstName', 'LastName']`, Python tries to turn `('FirstName', 'LastName')` into a tuple and use that as an index. But the dict returned from `json.loads` doesn't have tuples as indices. So instead, you need to look up each field separately and `join` them together.

```
# simulate loading playerdata
players = [
    {'FirstName': 'Podge', 'LastName': 'Hasglow'},
    {'FirstName': 'Milo', 'LastName': 'Holloway'},
    {'FirstName': 'Staisy', 'LastName': 'Beccasdaughter'},
]
# or in your case:
##players = json.loads(playerdata)
# now print them all
for player in players:
    player_fullname = ' '.join(player[colname] for colname in ['FirstName', 'LastName'])
    print(player_fullname)
```

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. where you have used a method of simulating the load, what syntax should i use for my actual load? the same regex i have now?

Comment: Try `players = json.loads(playerdata)` with the same regex.